# How to enclose a string within quotes using Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a string like this : `abc,bcd,def` but I need this string to be enclosed by single quotes, like this `'abc,bcd,def'`.

How can i get that using perl??

Thanks!

Comment: This is a somewhat basic question to ask. Did you really not know how to use double quotes? `"'$string'"`?

Comment: @TLP Well this is really a basic one but again if I really knew this i wouldn't ask here right... :) (P.S. first time coding in PERL that too an existing one, STACK OVERFLOW is the only reason I am alive!!! )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
my $stringWithSingelQuotes = "'abc,bcd,def'";
print $stringWithSingelQuotes;

Result: 
'abc,bcd,def'
```

or

```
my $stringWithSingelQuotes = "'".'abc,bcd,def'."'";
print $stringWithSingelQuotes;

Result: 
'abc,bcd,def'
```

you can even mix singel and double quotes:

```
my $stringWithMixedQuotes = "'".'abc,bcd,def'.'"';
print $stringWithMixedQuotes;

Result: 
'abc,bcd,def"
```

Comment: WOW... that was just great... And i cannot believe i didnt get that one... anyways, Thanks @Hubert!!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have the string to be quoted in a variable (e.g., `$string`) you can just use the double quotes to build the new one (e.g., `"'$string'"`).

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'abc,bcd,def';
my $newstring = "'$string'";

print "$newstring\n";
```

If you want assign the value to a variable you can use double quotes

```
    my $string = "'abc,bcd,def'";
```

or `q{}`

```
    my $string = q{'abc,bcd,def'};
```

Comment: I like how "'$string'" is totally not at all the same as '"$string"'